# Listbox events firing strangely

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listbox

I'm confused. I am basically trying to tell when the user has clicked something in the listbox, held the button, and left the listbox. Here is a somewhat dumbed down version of what I am doing:

```
private bool itemHeld;
    private void listOriginal_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        itemHeld = true;
    }

    private void listOriginal_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        itemHeld = false;
    }

    private void listOriginal_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (itemHeld)
            MessageBox.Show("OHH YEAH");
    }
```

To me that seems like it should turn itemHeld true when you press the mousebutton, turn it false only if you lift it, and display ohh yeah if the value is true. If I break on the mouse down event to check the value, it is true and if I continue from there it displays the message. If I do not break, it does nothing. Is there something else at work here?

Edit:
Brief description: It would be difficult to explain what I am really trying to accomplish but imagine something almost like dragging a file off of a window. I need to simply be able to recognize when the user clicks inside of the listbox and then drags out of the listbox if that makes sense

Comment: What do you mean by breaking the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this?

```
private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.X > listBox1.Width - 1 || e.Y > listBox1.Height - 1 || e.X < 0 || e.Y < 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("drag out");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("mouse move {0}/{1}", e.X, e.Y);
}
```

it uses the fact that the Control is not left before the mousebutton is released ... but be aware that the drag out part will occur more than once so you probably will want to have a flag set the first time ... and have that flag cleared on mouse up or leave

Comment: It will take a bit of tweaking for what I want exactly but this does essentially what I need it to. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can not debug windows events by break point because when the Visual Studio get active to debug, the mouse leave event will be fired for the hovered control.

You can use [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) which writes information about the debug to the trace listeners.

```
private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Mouse leave");
}

private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Mouse enter");
}

private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Mouse hover");
}
```

[image: The output will be]

Answer (score 1):

For every mouse click, your MouseDown event will fire AND your MouseUp event will fire, so the sequence of operations is equivalent to

```
itemHeld = true;
itemHeld = false;
if(itemHeld)
    MessageBox.Show("yay");
```

If you press the mouse button on the listbox and move the cursor out without releasing the button, switching focus to another window (e.g. Visual Studio) is what triggers the MouseLeave event to fire. This is why you're seeing the message box pop up when you're debugging.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't recommend another solution.

Comment: I have seen you on guitars :)

Comment: @André I use a few different SE sites. :)

Comment: internet is such a small place uh? see ya

Comment: Ok that's good to know that the mouse up always fires before the mouse leave will. I added a little description of what I want to accomplish in the post

Comment: @Nick Do you envision the user actually clicking on an item and then dragging it out of the listbox or is it just a click anywhere on the listbox and the items don't matter?

Comment: @Anna items don't really matter