# VBA: ListBox Change event firing twice

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a User Form in Excel in which questions are indexed in a Listbox control. Clicking on an item in the Listbox calls a Change event which populates other controls' values according to which item has been selected.

The user may change values within the text boxes. Upon changing them, a "Saved" flag gets set to False for that question. The user may then save the question into memory; or navigate away from the question.

If the user navigates away without saving (by means of clicking a different item in the Listbox), I want to present them with a warning - giving the option to either abandon their unsaved changes; or to remain with the current selection, and revert the Listbox selection which they just clicked.

If "Abandon changes" is selected, it works fine. However it runs into trouble when I try to revert the Listbox selection. I use an "EventsOn" Boolean to handle when the Change procedure should proceed, to avoid it calling itself. **This seems to work, at the correct point in the code.** However after EventsOn is reinstated, and after *Exit Sub*, it seems that the Change event is called **again**.

I do not know why the event is firing again. This results in the user being presented with the option a second time.

A lot of the following code has been stripped out because it relates to details of other form controls; loading/saving data from a database; and handling classes and dictionaries. However I have retained the relevant logic of the form controls:

```
Option Explicit
Dim NumberOfQuestions As Long
Dim EventsOn As Boolean
Dim SelectedListIndex As Long, CurrentQuestion As Long, QuestionSaved As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Stripped out lots of code here. Basically opens a recordset and loads values
    ReDim QuestionSaved(1 To NumberOfQuestions) As Boolean
    '
    For X = 1 To NumberOfQuestions
        lbox_QuestionList.AddItem "Question " & X ' Populate the listbox with items
        QuestionSaved(X) = True ' Flag the initial state as saved, for each question
        If Not X = rst.RecordCount Then rst.MoveNext
    Next X
    '
    ' Select the first question by default. Note that the Listbox ListIndex starts at 0, whereas the questions start at 1
    SelectedListIndex = 0
    CurrentQuestion = 1
    EventsOn = True
    lbox_QuestionList.ListIndex = SelectedListIndex
End Sub

Private Sub lbox_QuestionList_Change()
    ' Ensure this event does NOT keep firing in a loop, when changed programmatically
    If Not EventsOn Then Exit Sub
    '
    If Not QuestionSaved(CurrentQuestion) Then
        If MsgBox(Prompt:="Abandon changes to current question?", Title:="Current question not saved", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then
            ' Abandon changes = Yes
            ' Mark as saved
            QuestionSaved(CurrentQuestion) = True
            ' Then proceed to change as normal
            ' (If the user comes back to this question, it will be re-loaded from memory in its original form)
            ' This works okay
        Else
            ' Abandon changes = No
            EventsOn = False ' So this sub is not called again
            ' REVERT the ListBox selection. Do this by recalling the current question number, and applying it to the ListIndex
            SelectedListIndex = CurrentQuestion - 1 ' Remember that the index will be minus 1, due to indexing starting at 0
            lbox_QuestionList.ListIndex = SelectedListIndex
            EventsOn = True
            Exit Sub ' This should be the end of it. But somehow, it's not...
        End If
    End If
    ' Proceed with loading a new question according to the new selected ListIndex
    SelectedListIndex = lbox_QuestionList.ListIndex ' Recognise the current selection
    ' ListIndex starts at zero, so we need to add 1
    CurrentQuestion = SelectedListIndex + 1
    ShowQuestion CurrentQuestion
End Sub

Private Sub ShowQuestion(QuestionNumber As Long)
    ' Stripped out code for brevity. Basically loads details from a dictionary of classes, and populates into textboxes
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Save_Click()
    ' Stipped out code. Takes values of current text boxes and saves them into a class in a dictionary
    ' Mark the current question as saved:
    QuestionSaved(CurrentQuestion) = True
End Sub

''''''''''' Event handlers ''''''''''''''
Private Sub tb_Question_Change()
    DoChange
End Sub
' Several other form controls have similar events: all calling "DoChange" as below

Private Sub DoChange()
    If Not EventsOn Then Exit Sub
    QuestionSaved(CurrentQuestion) = False ' Flag the current question as NOT saved, if any changes are made to form values
End Sub
```

Naturally, I have searched for this problem - but there are no answers so far which have assisted me:

- [Listbox events firing strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682012/listbox-events-firing-strangely) - relates to C# and not VBA
- [listbox selected item changed event fired two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671916/listbox-selected-item-changed-event-fired-two-times) - relates to C# and not VBA
- [vba listbox event fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623581/vba-listbox-event-fires-twice) - suggests that a SetFocus method of the Listbox could solve the issue. However I have tried this, and the problem remains

The logic of my code seems sound. The mystery is why the Change event is being called a second time, even after *Exit Sub*.

Comment: +1 just for the excellently asked question, rare to see this kind of question quality with a specific description of the problem, provided code, what you've tried, and shown attempts at self-solving.

Comment: @PeterT - Actually I was originally using Click, and tried Change instead when Click wasn't working. They appear to behave identically. You tested my code as is? Sorry I didn't provide an easy example to copy/paste, as it involves a UserForm. But unsure how to explain how Click works for you but not me...

Comment: My mistake, and my apologies. During testing, I had commented out the `lbox_QuestionList.ListIndex = SelectedListIndex` statement. So when I converted the sub to "Click" I experienced an unsubstantiated aha! moment. :(

Comment: @PeterT - Thanks, I appreciate you testing this in any case!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this (F8) to see what really happens? I suspect this may come from the recursiveness of the event procedure - that since it's firing from "within itself" the `ExitSub` may not be doing what you expect...

Comment: @CindyMeister - Yes, I stepped through it line by line - and `Exit Sub` does indeed exit, but there's no logic of why the event is called again. Anyway, it looks like AfterUpdate works properly (as answered below by @PeterT)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(curses to OP for getting this problem in my brain!)*

In my testing, I used the following UserForm:

[image]

The code below uses the `ListBox1_AfterUpdate` event, and I believe it may work for you.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const TOTAL_QUESTIONS As Long = 3
Private qSaved As Variant
Private selectedDuringTextboxChange As Long
Private eventsInProgress As Long

Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "listbox clicked, item " & (ListItemSelected() + 1) & " selected"
    If eventsInProgress > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "   ... event in progress, exiting"
        eventsInProgress = eventsInProgress - 1
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not qSaved(selectedDuringTextboxChange) Then
        Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
        answer = MsgBox("Abandon changes?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2)
        If answer = vbYes Then
            Debug.Print "yes, abandon the changes"
            qSaved(selectedDuringTextboxChange) = True
        Else
            Debug.Print "nope, keep the changes"
            '--- return to the previously selected list item
            eventsInProgress = eventsInProgress + 1
            UnselectAll
            ListBox1.Selected(selectedDuringTextboxChange - 1) = True
            ListBox1.ListIndex = selectedDuringTextboxChange - 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub QuitButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
    qSaved(ListBox1.ListIndex + 1) = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    selectedDuringTextboxChange = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1
    qSaved(selectedDuringTextboxChange) = False
    Debug.Print "changed text for question " & selectedDuringTextboxChange
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ReDim qSaved(1 To TOTAL_QUESTIONS)

    selectedDuringTextboxChange = 1
    With ListBox1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To TOTAL_QUESTIONS
            .AddItem "Question " & i
            qSaved(i) = True
        Next i
        .Selected(0) = True
    End With
    eventsInProgress = False
End Sub

Private Sub UnselectAll()
    eventsInProgress = eventsInProgress + 1
    With ListBox1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(i) = False
        Next i
    End With
    eventsInProgress = eventsInProgress - 1
End Sub

Private Function ListItemSelected() As Long
    ListItemSelected = -1
    With ListBox1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                ListItemSelected = i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Private Sub WhichListItem_Click()
    With ListBox1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Debug.Print "listbox item(" & i & ") = " & .Selected(i)
        Next i
    End With
    Debug.Print "eventsInProgress = " & eventsInProgress
End Sub
```

Comment: All I had to do was use AfterUpdate instead of Change or Click - and it's now working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After looking into it for awhile, it appears that having the listbox set its own listindex from within its own change event (effectively recursively calling it) causes some weird backend issues.  Fortunately, it's easy enough to deal with by migrating that bit out to its own function.  After some experimenting, the best way to do it would be to create a function that clears and repopulates the listbox, so create this function in your UserForm code:

```
Private Function PopulateListbox(Optional ByVal arg_lSelected As Long = -1)

    Me.lbox_QuestionList.Clear

    Dim X As Long '
    For X = 1 To NumberofQuestions
        lbox_QuestionList.AddItem "Question " & X ' Populate the listbox with items
        QuestionSaved(X) = True ' Flag the initial state as saved, for each question
        'If Not X = rst.RecordCount Then rst.MoveNext
    Next X

    Me.lbox_QuestionList.ListIndex = arg_lSelected

End Function
```

Now adjust your Initialize event to look like this (note that you need to define `NumberofQuestions` here, and then call the new function at the end to populate the listbox and select the first entry):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Stripped out lots of code here. Basically opens a recordset and loads values

    NumberofQuestions = 3  'This is where NumberofQuestions gets defined
    ReDim QuestionSaved(1 To NumberofQuestions)
    ReDim aAnswers(1 To NumberofQuestions)

    '
    ' Select the first question by default. Note that the Listbox ListIndex starts at 0, whereas the questions start at 1
    SelectedListIndex = 0
    CurrentQuestion = 1
    EventsOn = True
    PopulateListbox SelectedListIndex  'Call the new function and set the 1st selection

End Sub
```

Lastly, update your listbox_change event to look like this (basically just outsourcing the setting of the listbox entry to the new function):

```
Private Sub lbox_QuestionList_Change()

    ' Ensure this event does NOT keep firing in a loop, when changed programmatically
    If Not EventsOn Then Exit Sub
    '
    If Not QuestionSaved(CurrentQuestion) Or aAnswers(CurrentQuestion) <> Me.tb_Question.Text Then   'I added the second condition for testing purposes, may not be necessary in your full code
        If MsgBox(Prompt:="Abandon changes to current question?", Title:="Current question not saved", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then
            ' Abandon changes = Yes
            ' Mark as saved
            QuestionSaved(CurrentQuestion) = True
            ' Then proceed to change as normal
            ' (If the user comes back to this question, it will be re-loaded from memory in its original form)
            ' This works okay
        Else
            ' Abandon changes = No
            EventsOn = False ' So this sub is not called again
            ' REVERT the ListBox selection. Do this by recalling the current question number, and applying it to the ListIndex
            SelectedListIndex = CurrentQuestion - 1 ' Remember that the index will be minus 1, due to indexing starting at 0
            PopulateListbox SelectedListIndex 'Call your new function here

            EventsOn = True
            Exit Sub ' This should be the end of it. But somehow, it's not...
        End If
    End If
    ' Proceed with loading a new question according to the new selected ListIndex
    SelectedListIndex = lbox_QuestionList.ListIndex ' Recognise the current selection
    ' ListIndex starts at zero, so we need to add 1
    CurrentQuestion = SelectedListIndex + 1
    ShowQuestion CurrentQuestion
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a **Private Sub ListBox_Click()** running twice.

When I cleared the *ControlSource* in the list box properties it fixed the problem. I had to add a line of code to specifically write the value from the *listbox* to the cell in the worksheet. At first the cell would not display the data so I set the range name to another cell and that was OK. So, I then dragged and dropped the new cell into the original location.

I don't understand where the problem originated, but the fix worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar unexpected issue, so maybe someone will find this result helpful.
Within a multi-selection-enabled Listbox_Change event, I checked the value of the currently-selected item to see whether it had been checked or unchecked.

```
    Private Sub lstBox_Change()
        With lstBox
            If .Selected(.ListIndex) Then
                ' Call Method A.
            Else
                ' Call Method B.
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

When the list was checked, it would properly detect the selection and call A--but then, when stepping through the code and reaching the Change event's End Sub, the checkbox would automatically become unselected, and the Change event would fire again. Note that I wasn't setting any value in the ListBox itself; I was only checking to see whether the current item was checked or unchecked. But, somehow, that triggered it to unselect itself. (Also, this only seemed to happen on the first call to the Change event. Thereafter it behaved normally.)

I tried some of the other fixes, but *BeforeUpdate* and *AfterUpdate* never seemed to fire at all. The problem went away when I moved the selection test outside of the If statement and put the result into a Boolean instead:

```
    Private Sub lstBox_Change()
        With lstBox
            BooleanResult = (.Selected(.ListIndex) = True)
            If BooleanResult Then
                ' Call Method A.
            Else
                ' Call Method B.
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

After that, the ListBox consistently behaved as expected.